# All Combinations across All Rows and All Columns

Tags: python-3.x

This has been eating in my sleep for a more than a fortnight now. Any help in getting this accomplished in any language is would be greatly helpful. I have the following data. I want to build a large dataset covering all combinations across all rows and all columns. I figured a logic of combinations across 1 column in python using Combinations, however scaling it to this structure is proving to be a real challenge.

[Here is the source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DXaN.jpg)

So I have been able to build the following, i.e for all combinations across one column and all rows.

[Output of combinations across all rows and one column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPHsA.jpg)

However trying to extrapolate this across all columns and all rows is proving to be a challenge.
The key is that the Index(Market) has to be a concatenation of what's actually being added and so if I were to add column1 & column3 of row 1, it has to be

"Buy Corn at MM1 and Buy Salt at MM1", the value of which would be A + K

Similarly

"Buy Corn at MM1 and Sell Corn at MM2 and Buy Salt at MM3" = A + G + M

Comment: So what approach/code have you used?

Comment: I used Python and inter tools.combinations to get the first column combinations

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a "doing nothing" column aloneside with Buys and Sells.
Thus you can have 5^5 combinations with only one occasion wasted that does nothing for 5 times.